# Unexpected behaviour of MapAt with position {}

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, map

```
expr = {slot};
Position[expr, slot]
MapAt[f, expr, %[[1]]]
```

yields

```
{{1}}
{f[slot]}
```

as expected. However,

```
expr = slot;
Position[expr, slot]
MapAt[f, expr, %[[1]]]
```

yields

```
{{}}
slot
```

not

```
{{}}
f[slot]
```

as I'd expect. On the other hand, using

```
MapAt[f, slot, {{}}]
```

rather than

```
MapAt[f, slot, {}]
```

does yield

```
f[slot]
```

There seems to be a mismatch between what is returned by `Position` and what is used by `MapAt`, despite the documentation. Why is this? I don't really want to have to handle position `{}` as a special case. (The real context consists of varied nested list expressions, in general having more than one `slot` but also possibly consisting of just a single `slot`, where I want to manipulate each `slot` individually.)

`Extract` and `ReplacePart` also seem to behave like `MapAt`, expecting `{{}}` not `{}` for the whole expression.

Comment: Just for the record, `expr /. slot -> f[slot]` might be a simpler solution for your original problem, but your question is an interesting observation anyway, and I'm looking forward to answers. :)

Comment: `{}` isn't an actual position. `Position[{1, 2, 3}, 4]` also returns `{}`.

Comment: But `Position[{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}]` returns `{{}}` --- note the difference.

Comment: `expr /. slot -> f[slot]` doesn't meet my larger requirements. I want to control which occurrences of slot I change.

Comment: Yes, which is why `MapAt[f, slot, {{}}]` does work. So the function works as expected. Can't you use `@` instead?

Comment: No. `Position` returns a _list_ of positions. So the (single) position of `{1,2,3}` in `{1,2,3}`, returned by `Position`, is `{}`, _not_ `{{}}`.

Comment: You can use a list of position specifications instead of a single position specification. This resolves the ambiguity.  I.e. use `{{}}` instead of `{}`.  `{}` is interpreted as an empty list of position specifications, not as a single position specification.  If you use this in `Extract`, be aware that it will return a *list* of items as a result, i.e. `Extract[{1, 2, 3}, {{}}]` gives `{{1,2,3}}` (a list of a single result) instead of `{1,2,3}`.

Comment: I agree with you that this behaviour is fairly arbitrary.  The difficulty comes from having to decide whether the second argument of `Extract` (or related functions) is (1) an index (2) or a single position specification (3) or a list of position specifications.  If we think carefully, we can identify rules through which all this makes sense.  (a) a position specification is always a list (b) the second argument of `Extract` is interpreted as a list of position specifications whenever possible. But I don't think this will make you happy because you already know the solution.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thanks. I hadn't realised I could just wrap each position returned by `Position` in an extra pair of braces, e.g. `MapAt[f, expr, {#}] & /@ Position[expr, slot]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree that this behaviour is somewhat arbitrary. It comes from the ambiguity between indices, position specifications and lists of positions specifications. If we think carefully, we can identify the rules that Mathematica uses to resolve this ambiguity, but I am not sure that stating these rules will make you happy...

For simplicity, let us discuss only `Position` and `Extract`.  `MapAt` and `ReplacePart` behave the same way.

#### What can be the second argument of `Extract`?

`Extract` can take:

- an integer index
- a position specification
- a list of position specifications (but not a list of indices!)

#### Where is the ambiguity?

A position specification is *always a list of integers*. It can also be an empty list, `{}`, which refers to the entire expression.

`Extract` does accept simple integer indexes for convenience, but these are not considered proper position specifications.

Thus:

```
Extract[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, 1] (* single index *)
(* {1, 2, 3} *)

Extract[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, {1}] (* single position specification *)
(* {1, 2, 3} *)

Extract[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, {{1}}] (* a list of position specifications *)
(* {{1, 2, 3}} *)
```

You will notice that `{}` is ambiguous. It can be interpreted as either

- an (empty) list of position specifications
- or a single position specification (in which case it refers to the whole expression)

*`Extract` always prefers an interpretation as a list of position specifications!* Thus it interprets `{}` as an empty list of position specifications.

#### Why does it make sense for `Extract` to try to interpret its second argument as a list of position specifications?

Because that is what [`Position`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html) returns. It always, realiably returns a list. If `Position` retusn `{}`, it means that it did not find the pattern. If it returns `{{}}`, it means that the pattern matched the whole expression, but no subexpression of it.

Thus we can consistently use

```
Extract[expr, Position[expr, patt]]
```

This is the workaround to your problem. Do not extract the first position, or if you do, make sure to put it into a list.

Remember that when `Extract` receives a list of position specifications as its seond argument, it returns a list as the result.

Thus

```
Extract[{1, 2, 3}, {{}}]
(* {{1, 2, 3}} *)
```

The result is not `{1,2,3}` but `{{1,2,3}}`.

With `MapAt` and `ReplacePart` this is not an issue.

In certain cases, this behaviour generalizes well.  For example, to extract the first part of `expr` which matches `patt`, you can use

```
Extract[expr, Take[Position[expr, patt], UpTo[1]]]
```

This will work even when the pattern isn't found at all. It returns a list with zero or one elements.